# Time, bus, and probability

Tags: probability

I've come across a pretty nice question, that I don't know how to solve.

On your bus station, there are 2 buses - black one going to school, and white one going to university, each run's every 10 minutes. Each day Ben goes to the bus station at a random time, and catches the first bus that arrives.

Is the probability of getting to school and university always equal?

Thanks for any pointers in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the probabilities are not always the same. Suppose that the bus to shool arrives always 5 seconds after the university bus. Then the chances to go to school are very low.

Comment: Btw, how could I prove it using equations? And actually, is the only case when the probabilities are equal, when the buses are 5' apart?

Comment: Let $T$ be the time it takes for the white bus to arrive after the most recent black bus arrived. Then the probability of taking the white bus is $\frac{T}{10 m}$. This is so because B = the time that Ben arrives after the black bus is uniformly distributed between 0 minutes and 10 minutes. And Ben takes the white bus if $B<T$.